# Python (FLASK) - problem with importing from other modules

Tags: python, flask, import, module, importerror

i started writing my first Flask app, and encountered a problem. I have a file structure like this:
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wcrj.png)

Main file is karczma.py, which starts like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from config import Config
from forms import SessionForm
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
```

config.py is:

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'NOT-GONNA-SHOW-YOU-THAT'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://' + os.path.join(basedir,'thermos.db')
```

**init**.py is empty.

When i try to run the app, i get:
File "/home/niedzwiedx/Dokumenty/Python/karczma/karczma.py", line 6, in 
    from config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

What did i do wrong?

Comment: What's your current working directory when you execute the code?

Comment: @jordanm  - the very same where the files are